Analyzing Expected Profit in a Symmetric Random Walk with Trading Actions
Problem Formalization:
I am examining a problem where a stock price $X_t$ follows a symmetric random walk starting at 10, and increments or decrements by 1 unit at each step with equal likelihood. The process stops when the price hits 0 or 20. Initially, there are 10 coins, each purchased at a price of 10.
Trading rules:

If $X_t$ increases, I sell 1 coin.
If $X_t$ decreases, I buy 1 coin.

The aim is to analyze the expected profit at the end of the process. I have run simulations to observe the behavior and calculate approximate expected values, but I am seeking a more rigorous mathematical analysis of the expected outcomes and any stochastic modeling that can explain the observed results.
Simulation Code and Visualization:
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def simulate_stock_trading_profit():
    start = 10
    end_low = 0
    end_high = 20
    
    x = start
    stock_count = 10
    cost = start * (-stock_count)
    history_x = [x]
    history_stocks = [stock_count]
    history_profit = [0]  # Initialize profit/loss to 0
    buy_points = []
    sell_points = []

    while x > end_low and x < end_high:
        prev_x = x
        x += random.choice([-1, 1])  # Move randomly left or right
        history_x.append(x)

        if x > prev_x:  # Moving up, sell stock
            stock_count -= 1
            cost += x
            sell_points.append((len(history_x)-1, x))  # Record selling point
        elif x < prev_x:  # Moving down, buy stock
            stock_count += 1
            cost -= x
            buy_points.append((len(history_x)-1, x))  # Record buying point

        # Update profit/loss record
        current_profit = cost + (stock_count * x)
        history_stocks.append(stock_count)
        history_profit.append(current_profit)
    return buy_points, sell_points, history_x, history_stocks, history_profit

def visualize_stock_trading_profit(buy_points, sell_points, history_x, history_stocks, history_profit):
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.plot(history_x, label='Position (x)', color='blue', marker='', linestyle='-')
    plt.plot(history_stocks, label='Stock Count', color='green', marker='', linestyle='--')
    plt.plot(history_profit, label='Profit/Loss', color='red', marker='', linestyle='-.')
    plt.axhline(y=10, color='gray', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.75, label='Baseline (y=10)')

    # Mark buy and sell points
    if buy_points:
        buy_x, buy_y = zip(*buy_points)
        plt.scatter(buy_x, [history_x[i] for i in buy_x], color='lightgreen', label='Buy Points', marker='o', s=50)
    if sell_points:
        sell_x, sell_y = zip(*sell_points)
        plt.scatter(sell_x, [history_x[i] for i in sell_x], color='salmon', label='Sell Points', marker='x', s=50)

    plt.title('Position, Stock Count, and Profit/Loss Over Time with Trade Points')
    plt.xlabel('Step')
    plt.ylabel('Value')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

# Call the function to perform a simulation
visualize_stock_trading_profit(*simulate_stock_trading_profit())

# Simulate expected profit
trading_profit = []
cnt = int(1e8)
for i in range(cnt):
    profit = simulate_stock_trading_profit()[-1][-1]
    trading_profit.append(profit)

# Positive profit cases
positive_profits = [p for p in trading_profit if p > 0]
positive_count = len(positive_profits)
average_positive_profit = sum(positive_profits) / positive_count if positive_count > 0 else 0

# Negative profit cases
negative_profits = [p for p in trading_profit if p < 0]
negative_count = len(negative_profits)
average_negative_profit = sum(negative_profits) / negative_count if negative_count > 0 else 0

print(
    "Total simulations run: {}".format(cnt),
    "Maximum profit: {}".format(max(trading_profit)),
    "Minimum profit: {}".format(min(trading_profit)),
    "Average profit: {:.2f}".format(sum(trading_profit) / len(trading_profit)),
    "Count of positive profits: {}".format(positive_count),
    "Average positive profit: {:.2f}".format(average_positive_profit),
    "Count of negative profits: {}".format(negative_count),
    "Average negative profit: {:.2f}".format(average_negative_profit)
)

Attached Image:
Illustration
Simulation Results:

Total simulations run: 100,000,000
Maximum profit: 773
Minimum profit: -145
Average profit: -0.000117
Count of positive profits: 51,535,851
Average positive profit: 98.239414
Count of negative profits: 48,426,011
Average negative profit: -104.548431

Discussion:
In the simulation results, the expected profit approximates to zero. However, each time the price returns to the starting point, a profit is realized, leading to confusion about the zero result. I am seeking a rigorous mathematical explanation for these observations, focusing on the stochastic processes involved.
I would appreciate any insights or references to mathematical theories that could explain the dynamics observed in this simulation.

Consider the two extreme cases: when the stock goes from $X = 10$ to $X = 20$ in 10 consecutive upticks your profit is 55\$. However, when the stock goes from $X = 10$ to $X = 0$ in 10 consecutive down ticks your profit is -815\$.
There’s a clear asymmetry. The strategy does well when the stock goes up or oscillates, but it does TERRIBLY on the way down. Intuitively, if the stock is going right down to zero the absolute worst thing you can do is buy all the way down since your losses get compounded.
